# Sqli query row following members filter

Tags: mysql, database

hey its paradox here need some help in sql query

this is my query

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       user.fullname,
       user.username,user.id,
       user.profile_pic
FROM `user`,
     `following`,
     `followers`
WHERE user.id = user_id
  AND following_userID != '307';
```

This is the result I'm getting

```
fullname     username   id   profile_pic    
gdsdfg       dfsggd     314       fgd
rgxzcdf      dsczxfh    335     vgfsadz
rgdf          dfh       330       vgf
```

This is the result I want 314 should completely filtered because its comes in following user id of 307

```
fullname     username   id   profile_pic    

rgxzcdf      dsczxfh    335     vgfsadz
rgdf          dfh       330       vgf
```

here's the full db without query

```
                                         user_id following_userID uid   
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   314           306     2
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   313           307     3
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   314           307     14
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   307           307     15
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   335           999     18
    Edit Edit   Copy Copy   Delete Delete   330           999     19
```

how should i filter 314 i dont want similar id which user_id comes in 307

what im trying to make is select query for suggestion and suggestion users should not come if they are in following_userID
example if im following id 309 then 309 should not show in suggestion select query

Comment: Why are you still using that 1980's JOIN syntax? The ANSI-92 explicit JOIN syntax have been around for *30* years now; it's long past time you adopted it.

Comment: Could you provide sample data from those tables?

Comment: which sample you want?

Comment: From `user`, `following`,    `followers` tables

Comment: Sample from all 3 tables and also publish the output you want , the question is not clear..

Comment: Your last comment makes little sense in english you could clarify by adding Sample from all 3 tables and also publish the output you want

Comment: We dont understand anything to what you want

Comment: plz check i've updated the question

Comment: i just want user_id should not Show* if its comes in following_userID of 307 or any following_userID i entered